# Why does my world generation code perform poorly on large inputs?

Tags: procedural-generation, lua, bug

I'm writing some code to procedurally generate some islands in real time. The idea is to choose some points for each chunk, and for each tile calculate the distance from those points, then combine it with a Perlin Noise to decide  if it will be water or land. Anyway here's the code:

```
local function number()
    local n = math.random()
    if n < .4 then
        return 0
    elseif n < .8 then
        return 1
    end
    return 2
end
```

Just a custom weighted random function, used to choose how many points will be in each chunk.

```
chunks = setmetatable({}, {
    __index = function(tab, x)
        local xtab = setmetatable({}, {
            __index = function(xtab, y)
                local xs, ys = x * 32, y * 32
                local islands = {}
                for i = 1, number() do
                    islands[i] = {x = math.random(xs, xs + 31), y = math.random(ys, ys + 31), r = math.random(16, 32)}
                end
                xtab[y] = islands
                return islands
            end})
        tab[x] = xtab
        return xtab
    end})
```

This block just initializes the chunks table, setting its metatable so that if a non existing chunk is being called, that chunk gets initialized by choosing a number of points the chunk will contain, and for each point choose its position inside the chunk and its range.

However here's the buggy code:

```
function generatechunk(x, y)
    local xs, ys = x * 32, y * 32
    for xm = xs, xs + 31 do
        for ym = ys, ys * 31 do
            for xc = x - 1, x + 1 do
                for yc = y - 1, y + 1 do
                    local points = chunks[xc][yc]
                    for p = 1, #points do
                        local po = points[p]
                        local d = math.max(0, math.min(math.sqrt((po.x - xm) ^ 2 + (po.y - ym) ^ 2) / po.r, 1))
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It isn't even completed yet. Basically what it should do is choosing for each tile if it will be sea or land by combining the Perlin Noise value and the influences of the points of the chunks around its chunk.

But here's the bug: if I call (for testing) `generatechunk(n, n)` for n <= 0, it executes in little to no time. But as n increases I get results of about n seconds of execution. Why is it?

Comment: `for ym = ys, ys * 31 do` <- should that maybe be `ys + 31` like in the previous line?

Comment: I am also a bit suspicious of some hidden bottlenecks lurking in your `chunks` metatable code, but I don't know enough LUA to be sure.

Comment: Narrow it down more. How many times do those nested `for` loops execute?

Comment: It has to do with the complexity of your generateChunks function.

Comment: @Philip *facepalm* yeah it should be `ys + 31`, I didn't notice that at all ._.

Comment: Now it's perfectly working. Anyway is 0.1 seconds a too big delay for a game or is it okay?

Comment: @user6245072 Whether or not a 100ms delay is too long or not depends on when that delay occurs and how often. You can not generalize that. When it is notable during playtesting you might want to open a new question asking about how to mitigate or hide that delay.

Comment: It's really a 180 ms delay, and it happens very often :I

Comment: Breaking the chunks in smaller ones should help tho. I got to test this out.